# How can i get the context of a jquery-ui autocomplete widget?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, this, jquery-ui-autocomplete, attr

I'm using jQueryUI Autocomplete for a web project. I need get the `name` attribute of every called `input`. How can I get it? `this` can't get the context inside of the function.

```
$("input").autocomplete({
  delay: 600,
  minLength: 2,
  source: function(request, response) {
    var term = request.term; 
    $.getJSON(url, request, function(data, status, xhr) {
      response(data);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I have several inputs, so i need to know who is triggering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by initialising the autocomplete inside an `each()` loop. This will mean you have access to the `this` reference:

```
$("input").each(function() {
  var $input = $(this);

  $input.autocomplete({
    delay: 600,
    minLength: 2,
    source: function(request, response) {
      var term = request.term; 
      // do something with $input.prop('name') here...
      $.getJSON(url, request, function(data, status, xhr) {
        response(data);
      });
    } 
  });
});
```